# Camel log error

Tags: scala, apache-camel, dsl

I use scala camel dsl and  I need to catch exceptions.

My pipeline doesn't log anything in `handle` case:

```
  s"$ftpSource"
    .log("File is received")
    .as(classOf[String])
    .attempt{
      process(failingProcessor)
    }.handle(classOf[Exception]) apply {
      process((exchange: Exchange) => logger.error(s"Error during file reading: ${exchange.in.toString}"))
    }
```

How to properly catch exceptions using scala dsl? And how to specify rollback strategy? I dont want it to retry in case of failure.

The only small poor example I've found is:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-scala/src/test/scala/org/apache/camel/scala/dsl/TryCatchFinallyTest.scala

Comment: p.s. only "cast" the contents of the file to a string when the file is very small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opinionated answer..

IMHO you should try and use camel as a *declarative* language. I always find the 'try...catch' dsl too *imperative*

Here is an example of using a more declarative exception handler

```scala
handle[MyException] {
  log("handling exception")
  process((e : Exchange) => e.in = "an error occured")
}.handled

"jetty:http://localhost:9091/service" ==> {

  id ("some-error-route")
  log("processing request")
  process((e : Exchange) => e.in = e.in[String].reverse)
  process((_: Exchange) => throw new MyException("Something went wrong"))
  log("done")

}
```

I recommend you check out the excellent book [Camel In action](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action) for different ways of handling errors.